# In PHP If XML Element Contains Certain Text

Tags: php, xml

In PHP is it possible to search an XML document for certain text in an element? I've looked but I can't find something that satisfies my needs.

Comment: Indeed it is. Have a look at SimpleXML, DOMDocument or XMLReader. The first two are quite simple, so go for one of them. You'll probably want to run an XPath query to do your search.

Comment: (Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way. It's worth familiarising yourself with the posting guidelines - there is an expectation that questions demonstrate solid prior research, and it is better if they focus on a code problem featuring code than a design-stage problem. The latter are often regarded as too broad. Lastly if you have specific needs, then spell them out - it's hard for people to help if you say you have criteria, but you don't say what those criteria are.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure you can do that using strpos function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
if(strpos($xml_str, "string_to_search_for")){
    echo "Found";
}
```

Comment: But if you want to find the acronym "html", then this will incorrectly find all the `<html>` tags too.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway to have `$xml_str = link` to XML document?

Comment: $xml_str = string of XML document if you want to get the xml from a link you can use file_get_contents function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: This is some **extremely bad advice**. XML is not unstructured text. You need to treat it like XML, not like a string.

Comment: Would be better if you could modify this answer to use an XML parser. Downvoting for now - I agree with Kuba that this isn't best practice.